# Nginx Virtual Host for external subdomain

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble **setting up a subdomain to a directory on my droplet** (digital ocean):

I have my domain primarydomain.com of my droplet...i create a directory /livezilla/

Example:

***primarydomain.com/livezilla***

I want ***add a external subdomain to this directory*** (livezilla):

**chat.myotherdomain.com.br**

I have in: /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/primarydomain.com:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name primarydomain.com;

location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;

}
}
```

And

/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/chat.myotherdomain.com.br

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name chat.myotherdomain.com.br;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/livezilla/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

(with a copy on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled)

The **chat.myotherdomain.com.br have a A Record** in dns pointing to my droplet..

chat.myotherdomain.com.br now redirects to myotherdomain.com.br but with ping shows my droplet ip. )):

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see it: `Host chat.myotherdomain.com.br not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my question. Wtf.

```
server {
        listen chat.myotherdomain.com.br:80;
        server_name chat.myotherdomain.com.br;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/livezilla;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

     location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}
```